# Functions satisfying $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\ \mathbb{N}$ and $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=n+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f$ such that $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\  \mathbb{N}$ and $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=n+2$

Let us plug in $n=1$

$f(f(1))+f(2)=3$

Since the function is from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, $f(2)$ can only take the values $1,2$. Now we divide the problem into cases.

**Case-1:** $f(f(1))=2,f(2)=1$

We can assume that $f(1)=c$ for the time being. Then plugging in $n=3$ and using $f(2)=1$ gives $$f(3)=4-c$$ and again since the range of the function is positive integers,then $4-c$ has to be positive and hence $c$ belongs to  {$1,2,3$}. Now, $$f(1)=c$$$$\implies f(f(1))=f(c)$$$$\implies 2=f(c)$$ by the assumption that $f(f(1))=2$ . Now,since $c$ can only take the values $1,2,3$,we start treating cases. If $c=1$,$$f(c)=2$$$$\implies f(1)=2$$ but we know from the deinition of $c$ that $f(1)=c=1$,a contradiction.If $c=2$,then $2=f(c)=f(2)$ but $f(2)=1$ by assumption. Finally,if $c=3$ $$2=f(c)=f(3)$$ but $$f(3)=4-c=4-3=1$$ which is once again a contradiction. Therefore there are no such functions in this case.

**Case-2:** $f(f(1))=1,f(2)=2$

Again assuming $f(1)=c$ and using $f(n)\le n$ along with plugging $n=c-1$ will give us that $f(1)=1$ and then it is easy to prove that such a function exists by recursion. I can only give a "sort of recursive" way to define the function. Here it goes $$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$$$f(1)=1$$$$f(n)=n+1-f(f(n-1))$$

But this case is harder to deal with.Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also,the first few values starting from n=1 are $1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10$. I have tried proving that the function is non-decreasing,but have failed.It is perhaps too much to say the values don't follow any pattern,but I cannot see any pattern that will help me find a closed form expression.It might also help to prove that the function is surjective(onto).

Comment: OEIS is your friend! [OIES A019446](https://oeis.org/A019446) $a(n) = \left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi} \right\rceil$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ration matches your sequence (at least up to $n = 100$).

Comment: Since you are asked to "find all functions $f$", isn't it sufficient to show that there is only one such function, and it is uniquely determined by the given recursion? (The fact that the recursion works follows from $f(n)\le n$, which is easily proved via induction.)

Comment: @Rahul,yes it is.But I am extremely curious how we could have come up with the achille hui's OEIS solution above.

Comment: @achille,interesting.I suppose the presence of a floor or ceiling was expected,given the nature of the values.Any ideas how we could have come up with it?Thanks for the OEIS link btw.

Comment: @Rahul,btw,induction is an overkill.Just note that $f(n+1)=n+2-f(f(n))\le n+2-1=n+1$.

Comment: @rah4927 No idea. However, one of the ref there does mention this sequence is a solution of your last recurrence relation. (by Benoit Cloitre, Nov 06 2002)

Comment: Problem 11651 of the American Mathematical Monthly is closely related to your problem (see the solution [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.06.549)). Also, see [this paper](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-4/carlitz.pdf).

Comment: As noted, we get for all $n>1$:$$(i)\;f(n) = n+1 -f(f(n-1))\le n+1 - 1 = n$$Since $f(f(1))+f(2)=3$, there must be some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n) > 1$. For that $n$, we get:$$
(ii)\;f(n+1) = n + 2 -f(f(n))\ge n+2-f(n) \ge 2$$
So that $f(n+1)$ is also $>1$. We conclude that if $f(n) > 1$ holds for some $n$, the it also holds for all integers greater that $n$. This implies that $f(1)=1$, since otherwise, we would have both $f(2)\ge2$, and $f(f(1))\ge2$ - a contradiction.
Note that $(ii)$ may be rewritten as:$$f(n)+f(n+1) \ge n+2$$However, by $(i)$ we also have:$$f(n)+f(n+1)\le2n+1$$

Comment: @achillehui,I don't know if there is a proper way to figure out the closed form expression of the function.Any ideas how we can prove that the closed form expression does follow the recurrence?

Comment: @rah4927 I have added an answer which shows $\left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi}\right\rceil$ is a solution of the functional equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer doesn't attempt to solve following functional equation from first principle.

$$f(n+1) + f(f(n)) = n+2,\quad\text{ for } n \ge 1\tag{*1}$$

Instead, it verify the function $\left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi}\right\rceil$ appeared
in [OEIS A019446](https://oeis.org/A019446) is a solution of $(*1)$.

For any fixed $n \ge 1$, since $\phi$ is irrational, there exists 3 numbers $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3 \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$
\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{\phi} \right\rceil = \frac{n+1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1,
\quad
\left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi} \right\rceil =  \frac{n}{\phi} + \epsilon_2,
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\left\lceil\frac{1}{\phi}\left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi} \right\rceil\right\rceil
= \frac{1}{\phi}\left\lceil \frac{n}{\phi} \right\rceil + \epsilon_3
$$

Substitute this into $(*1)$, this is equivalent to showing:

$$\left( \frac{n+1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 \right) + \frac{1}{\phi}\left(\frac{n}{\phi} + \epsilon_2\right) + \epsilon_3 \stackrel{?}{=} n + 2
\iff ( \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 ) + \frac{\epsilon_2}{\phi} + \epsilon_3 \stackrel{?}{=} 2
$$
There are two possible cases:

- If $\epsilon_2 < \frac{1}{\phi}$,

$$\frac{n+1}{\phi} > \left\lceil\frac{n}{\phi}\right\rceil
\implies
\frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2 + 1
\implies
\left( \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 \right) + \frac{\epsilon_2}{\phi} = \phi \epsilon_2 + 1 \in (1,2)
$$

- If $\epsilon_2 \ge \frac{1}{\phi}$,
  $$\frac{n+1}{\phi} \le \left\lceil\frac{n}{\phi}\right\rceil
  \implies 
  \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2
  \implies
  \left( \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 \right) + \frac{\epsilon_2}{\phi} = \phi\epsilon_2 \in [1,\phi)
  $$

In both cases, since $\epsilon_3 \in (0,1)$, we have
$$\left( \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 \right) + \frac{\epsilon_2}{\phi} \in [1,2)
\implies 
\left( \frac{1}{\phi} + \epsilon_1 \right) + \frac{\epsilon_2}{\phi} + \epsilon_3 \in (1,3)
$$
Since by construction, the LHS of this expression is an integer, it has to be $2$
and hence $(*1)$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

So we start by the fact that $f(k) ≤ k$ for any $k$ and we can determine using strong induction on $n$ the value of $f (n)$ : if we have known $f(1),f(2),...,f(k)$ then by setting $n = k + 1$ we compute $f(k + 1)$. (This is already mentioned above)

But this (strong induction) **implies that $f$ is defined uniquely**

And, as was shown in the [first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097958/functions-satisfying-f-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-and-ffnfn1-n/1101540#1101540), The function $f(x) = [cx]+1 $ where $c = \frac{√5−1}{ 2}$ is a solution, hence it's the only solution.